# Where to start managing transactions in java SOA application

Tags: java, transactions, soa

i'm starting to work with Services in Java, and i've been googleing for a while but i still have no clue when is need to handle transactions y several services, e.g. if creating a client uses 3 services, and the third service crash, how can i roll back the 2 previous services? any link, or explanation could help

Comment: Do you want to use service technologies for remoting, or do you want to start working on building applications based on SOA?

SOA is more than using service technologies like SOAP to perform a remote call. In a SOA each service is defined by a contract and if you need to be able to 'undo' the effects of a call you need to include that possibility in the service definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need distributed transations, which is exactly what the [Java Transaction API](http://java.sun.com/javaee/technologies/jta/index.jsp) is for. Application servers like [Spring](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-2009/jw-01-spring-transactions.html) or [Java EE's EJB container](http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/transaction-annotations.html) support JTA and make it very easy to use via annotations or declarative configuration.

Comment: I finally fixed using the JTA classes XAResource, Xid and XConnection =)

Answer (score 1):

If a client needs to call multiple service methods transactionally, then you'd better create a [facade class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) which executes the 3 operations, transactionally.

If the operations require user input in between - don't do it. Such long-running transactions are prime candidates for performance problems and deadlocks.